# COMException for DLL in C# but not in VB

Tags: c#, comexception

I am trying to access a COM interface of an application from a C# project. I have an example that runs in VB. This means that the DLL should be registered etc.

If I try this in c# with:

```
using Library;
...
Fruit a = new Library.Fruit();
```

Then it throws an COMExeception 80040154 class not registered. However, things like:

```
using Library;
...
Car b = new Library.Car();
```

still work for some reason?! What could be the solution?

Comment: It is not the DLL that gets registered, but the individual classes. So it seems that the Car class is registered, but the Fruit class is not.

Comment: Hm, how do I solve this. Is this an issue with my project settings? I can run the VB project that calls Fruit without problems.

Comment: It may help to see the VB.NET code that works. Are there any differences in bit-ness (32-bit vs. 64 bit) between the working app and the not working app?

Comment: Both projects target 32 bit. I dont know if this is important, but IntelliSense does show me the methods and properties available when I write the Fruit code. So this should work...

Comment: Did you look up the registration in regedit at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{your_clsid}` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{your_clsid}`? Any difference between the entries for Fruit and Car?

Comment: Yes, the Fruit entry is available in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID, but not in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\CLSID. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an assignment issue, where I mixed up the correct syntax during the translation from VB to C#.